# setInterval timer result not updating on innerHTML

Tags: javascript

I have a simple countdown code running on Javascript, and when I run this code,

```
    setInterval(function() {
    var currentTime = new Date();
    var futureTime = new Date(countDownDate);
    var s = futureTime.getTime() - currentTime.getTime();
    (seconds = parseInt((s / 1000) % 60)),
    (minutes = parseInt((s / (1000 * 60)) % 60)),
    (hours = parseInt((s / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24));

    hours = hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours;
    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

    var documenttitle = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;

    console.log(documenttitle);

        var remainingtime = documenttitle
        document.getElementById("remaining").innerHTML = remainingtime;
    }, 500);
```

the results from `console.log` works fine, 
[image: Console.log of the code]
but innerHTML constantly glitches. Flashing two different numbers but not updating. How do I fix this?

Comment: What is `countDownDate`?

Comment: Could you post your markup as well?

Comment: Could you upload to jsbin/jsfiddle and share a link with the full code including html?

Comment: [Looks fine to me?](https://jsfiddle.net/wh8tamk9/)

Comment: If you are updating the element with a string, shouldn't you be using `el.textContent` instead? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent#Differences_from_innerHTML

Comment: I also found this on the web, so I put in to a JSfiddle for you. https://jsfiddle.net/03w7eh9g/

Comment: @OriolGrau setting innerText or el.textContent or innerHTML all should work fine and the same. The only advantage of setting innerText or textContent is when you want to prevent the browser from treating the text string as html and creating those elements.

Comment: yeah, it's just a best practice for performance and security

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problems with your code, the code below it's the same as your code but with the variable countDownDate defined.
Maybe it's a problem with something else in your code.

```js
 var countDownDate = new Date();
 countDownDate.setMinutes ( countDownDate.getMinutes() + 30 );
 
 setInterval(function() {
    var currentTime = new Date();
    var futureTime = new Date(countDownDate);
    var s = futureTime.getTime() - currentTime.getTime();
    (seconds = parseInt((s / 1000) % 60)),
    (minutes = parseInt((s / (1000 * 60)) % 60)),
    (hours = parseInt((s / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24));

    hours = hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours;
    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

    var documenttitle = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;

    console.log(documenttitle);

        var remainingtime = documenttitle
        document.getElementById("remaining").innerHTML = remainingtime;
    }, 500);
```

```html
<div id="remaining">
  0
</div>
```